# PowerPoint Programmatically get current filename and save it

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I am attempting to programmatically save the currently opened powerpoint as a WMF file.

I cannot seem to find out how to do it...

The code I have so far is:

```
        // Create the reference variables
        PowerPoint.Application ppApplication = null;
        PowerPoint.Presentations ppPresentations = null;
        PowerPoint.Presentation ppPresentation = null;

        // Instantiate the PowerPoint application
        ppApplication = new PowerPoint.Application();

        // Create a presentation collection holder
        ppPresentations = ppApplication.Presentations;

        // Create an actual (blank) presentation
        ppPresentation = ppPresentations.Add(Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

        // Activate the PowerPoint application
        ppApplication.Activate();

        string myFileName = "myPresentation";

        // Save the presentation as a PPTX
        ppPresentation.SaveAs(myFileName, PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsWMV, Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue);
```

But this code seems to fire up a new instance of Powerpoint, create a blank powerpoint file and save it... which is almost what I want except I want it just to save the currently opened file.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: maybe this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Application.ActivePresentation.SaveAs(...) after you have activated it. Also, .ppSaveAsWMV doesn't show up on the reference to .SaveAs on MSDN (PP 2013 anyway).

Comment: spot on. many thanks. and thanks for the heads-up on the pp2013 support for wmv

Comment: I also found this. which helped me. hope it helps you.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/powerpoint-to-video/source/browse/trunk/PPTVideo/Program.cs

Comment: According to the Object Browser in the PPT VBA IDE:  Const ppSaveAsWMV = 37 (&H25) (Member of PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType).